# Login function only using second condition and not first

Tags: php

I would use my username when the username is the second condition but the email wouldn't work and then vise versa.  This is my code below all help is appreciated.  :)

```
    public function loginUser($usernameEmail,$password){

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email OR username = :usernameEmail");

    $query->execute(array(":usernameEmail"=>$usernameEmail));

    $rows = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(password_verify($password, $rows['password'])){

        $_SESSION['userID'] = $rows['userID'];

        $_SESSION['username'] = $rows['username'];

        $_SESSION['usergroup'] = $rows['usergroup'];

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }

}
```

Comment: invalid MySQL `WHERE email = ??? OR username=`

Answer (score 0):

You need to test the columns individually, then combine the tests with `OR`.

```
WHERE email = :usernameEmail OR username = :usernameEmail
```

You could also use `IN ()`:

```
WHERE :usernameEmail IN (email, username)
```

Your query is being parsed as

```
WHERE (email != FALSE) OR (username = :usernameEmail)
```

So it matches any non-empty `email` value.

Comment: Wah, thanks both of you I just kept overlooking that haha.